# Method of exciting a special mode in dielectric resonator

Tags: electromagnetism, dielectric, resonance, waveguide

A dielctric resonator was constructed in a sandwitch like structure.
The middle layer is saphire er=11.5 ,the top and bottom layers are diamond with er=5.68.
A special mode was excited artifficially in eigenmode solver.
The electric field rotating  around the saphire core and magnetic field  with a peak in the saphire layer.

The main problem is how do i excite such unique mode?
Is there some intuition i could follow?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: what are the mode pictures in the top, middle and bottom $xy$ planes?

Comment: Hello hyportnex,Its Y-Z plane where we cut the "cake" vertically and see all layers.Could you please help me with intuition regarding how to excite excite such unique mode?
It the 4th mode in order of excitation(there are modes behind it  regarding cuttof frequencies.

Comment: These are just generalities: a small loop is responsive to a magnetic field that is perpendicular to the loop's plane, a short wire is responsive to the electric field that is parallel with the wire. You seem to be new to this, so I suggest you study first some basic concepts about waveguides and antennas before jumping into more complex situations such as a multilayer dielectric resonator. See the volumes 8, 10 and 12, in https://www.jlab.org/info_resources/mitseries or the books of Pozar or Collin.

Comment: I can see that these are $yz$ plane plots, this is why asked for the $xy$ planes, also I do not know where these planes cut the circle. You have to be more precise to expect an answer...

Comment: and all the MIT Rad Lab books are also available on archive, for example, https://archive.org/details/waveguidehandboo0010nmar

Comment: Hello hyportnex, i have added X-Y plane H and E fields in the main thread. the last two photos are X-Y plane.does it help with giving a direction regarding what could excite such mode? 
I am reading the basic theory ,Is theree some spesific way i could try and focus to excite this mode.  
Thanks.

Comment: I  think you can try this: split the sapphire into two halves in the plane $yz$ and place a small loop, $\approx 1/4$ of the disk diameter surrounding the strong part of the $H$ field between the halves. You will have to adjust the width of the wire and the radius of the loop to match the probe to the field. This would be a symmetrical, "ground free" drive.  You could also try driving it by a differential (+/-) pair of wires one on each diamond (top/bottom) outside faces along the $y$ axis. You will have to adjust the width and length to match it. No guarantees.

Comment: Hello hyportnex, I have tried to visuale the sturcture you suggested in the photo shown in the link bellow.Is this what you mean? I am having trouble visualizing how should i split the spahire into two parts.
Could you please show how should i split it?Thanks.

https://ibb.co/ZKxtfv3

Comment: Your drawing is off: the loop should be in the very middle of the sapphire resonator where you show the peak H-field, and the outer ones should come from a pair of transmission line "wires" lying parallel with the E-field. But more importantly, your questions are getting into design engineering, unless it is home work in which case it is off-topic here, and in either case not really appropriate for this forum. I suggest that you ask them in the https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ forum where it will catch much more interest.